# Apparently random vector plotting: TSNE

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-learn, visualization, dimensionality-reduction

I have successfully created a vector model using Gensim's word2vec library. Distance between related vectors is good (that is to say that derived similarity makes sense from a human perspective).

However, attempting to map these vectors to a graph has proven challenging. Naturally the N dimensions of the vectors needs to be reduced in order to be plot-able: and to that end I've used TSNE.

```
import gensim, logging, os
import codecs
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import gensim, logging, os
from sklearn.manifold import TSNE

wvs = model.syn1neg
vocabulary = model.wv.vocab


tsne = TSNE(n_components=2, random_state=0)
np.set_printoptions(suppress=True)
Y = tsne.fit_transform(wvs[::])

plt.scatter(Y[:, 0], Y[:, 1])
for label, x, y in zip(vocabulary, Y[:, 0], Y[:, 1]):
    plt.annotate(label, xy=(x, y), xytext=(0, 0), textcoords='offset points')
plt.show()
```

However, the resulting points relating to the vectors appear to be essentially random - there is just a single huge cluster with a couple of outliers.

[image: math py graph]

A case in point: note the nearest neighbours to "hallucinating" at the edge of the cluster

[image: vectors]

But the actual vectors returned usng model.most_similar() are

> [('agitated', 0.7707732319831848), ('restless', 0.740711510181427),
>   ('disorientated', 0.7242116332054138), ('confused',
>   0.7215688228607178), ('aggressive', 0.71 69249057769775), ('drowsy', 0.6654224395751953), ('tearful', 0.6573441624641418) , ('aggitated', 0.6566967964172363), ('sleepy', 0.6562871932983398), ('shaking',
>    0.6419488191604614)]

What way can I begin to approach this to try and make the output be more sensible?

Comment: Read the docs and work with all those parameters. Of course, such a difficult task might need fine-tuning.

Comment: What is the shape of `wvs` and why are you skipping the first 100 for the TSNE (`wvs[100::]`)?

Comment: @ImanolLuengo dimensions are apparently (6708*100). Skipping was merely for testing purposes, I'll take it out of the quoted code

Comment: you may want to have a look at this t-SNE article as well http://distill.pub/2016/misread-tsne/

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely read the article linked by @MattiLyra. Beyond that based on what I know (without seeing the actual data), you may want to increase the `n_iter` parameter a good bit. Usually 1000 iterations isn't going to take you to a static state. Moreover, you may also want to play around with the `method` parameter. The documentation for [`sklearn.manifold.TSNE`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.manifold.TSNE.html) states:

> "By default the gradient calculation algorithm uses Barnes-Hut approximation running in O(NlogN) time. method=’exact’ will run on the slower, but exact, algorithm in O(N^2) time. The exact algorithm should be used when nearest-neighbor errors need to be better than 3%. However, the exact method cannot scale to millions of examples."

If you change the method to 'exact' you can use the `n_iter_without_progress` parameter and basically allow the model to find a static point.